# JavaScript delay when true in inner loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I have a situation that so far I have not been able to find a satisfactory solution for. Below is the code on a high level.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  o = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:10, e:11, f:12, g:7, h:8, i:9};

function matched(i, j) {
  return a[i]===o[j];
}

for (var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
  for (var j in o) {
    if (matched(i, j)) console.log(a[i]);
  }
}
```

I have an array and an object. I'm looping through the array, then the object, to find a match via the function `matched()` which returns a boolean `true` or `false`. If the condition is `true`, then I log the array item. If you run the code right now (https://jsfiddle.net/thdoan/0tubbokj/), you should see numbers 1-3 and 7-9 outputted to the console.

What I'm trying to do is to output the numbers with a one-second delay in between each number. I know how to introduce a delay in between each loop iteration, but I only want to add the delay for the numbers that are printed (i.e., when `matched()` returns `true`).

**Clarification:** My current solution, which I'm not satisfied with, is to save the matched items to a separate array and iterate over that array with a delay, but I'm looking for a solution that does not require creating a new array.

Comment: You need recursion for that. Change the loop `for()` with a recursive function. If you can't, you can `setTimeout(function() { console.log(result); },1000);` but it's not fine.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude can you demonstrate your solution in a fiddle or codepen because I couldn't get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is equal to the answer from TJCrowder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm trying to do is to output the numbers with a one-second delay in between each number.

You've also said in a comment:

> ...in the real app the matched set can grow to be very large, so I would rather not consume more memory if there is a solution that doesn't require outputting to a third array.

To achieve both of those goals, you have to completely abandon your `for` loops and instead do a chained series of `setTimeout`s.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  o = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:10, e:11, f:12, g:7, h:8, i:9};

function matched(i, j) {
  return a[i]===o[j];
}

// Get the property names in `o`, and start at the beginning
var keys = Object.keys(o);
var i = 0;
var keyIndex = 0;
tick();

function tick() {
  // Get the "j" value for this tick
  var j = keys[keyIndex];
  
  // Is this a match?
  var flag = matched(i, j);
  if (flag) {
    console.log(a[i]);
  }
  
  // Move to the next entry in our nested loops
  if (++keyIndex >= keys.length) {
    keyIndex = 0;
    if (++i >= a.length) {
      // Done
      return;
    }
  }

  // Continue
  if (flag) {
    // We output one, wait a second before next
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  } else {
    // No output, continue immediately
    tick(); // SEE NOTE BELOW
  }
}
```

NOTE: If there may be thousands of non-matches in a row, you might consider using a loop in `tick` instead of chaining to it. As of ES2015, JavaScript is supposed to have tail-call optimization and our `tick` wouldn't have to push itself on the stack (it would just call back to the beginning), but some JavaScript engines haven't implemented TCO yet, which could mean you'd end up with a *significant* stack depth.

So, with a loop:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  o = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:10, e:11, f:12, g:7, h:8, i:9};

function matched(i, j) {
  return a[i]===o[j];
}

// Get the property names in `o`, and start at the beginning
var keys = Object.keys(o);
var i = 0;
var keyIndex = 0;
tick();

function tick() {
  var match = findNextMatch();
  if (match) {
    console.log(match);
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
}

function findNextMatch() {
  var j;
  var match;
  
  while (!match && i < a.length) {
    j = keys[keyIndex];
    if (matched(i, j)) {
      match = a[i];
    }

    // Move to the next entry in our nested loops
    if (++keyIndex >= keys.length) {
      keyIndex = 0;
      ++i;
    }
  }

  return match;
}
```

Actually, that seems cleaner to me anyway, even without the deep stack concern.

Comment: Looks like this is what the OP wants. Functionally, this is the best answer :D +1

Comment: T.J Crowder I like your solution, it seems elegant to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @10basetom: The disadvantage to it is that it has to build and keep that array of the keys in `o`, which you said could be in the thousands. That said, "thousands" of strings in an array isn't a big deal in modern JavaScript environments, and you can release the array when done. The alternative would be to count your way up to the current "j" each time in a `for-in` loop, which A) Would have higher runtime cost (though not likely to be big enough to really matter, and B) Would rely on stable `for-in` iteration order. *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(cont'ing)* If you don't change `o`, I would expect stable `for-in` iteration order, but it's not guaranteed (not even in ES2015 and later). I bet it's reliable cross-engine, though. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is relatively simple:

Don't worry about the logging when you're gathering the results. Instead, store *all* results in a new array.

Then, iterate over that `result` array, with a delay:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    o = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:10, e:11, f:12, g:7, h:8, i:9},
    result = [];

function matched(i, j) {
  return a[i]===o[j];
}

for (var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
  for (var j in o) {
    if (matched(i, j))
      result.push(a[i]); // Store the found result.
  }
}

var i = 0,
    length = result.length;

(function iterator() {
    console.log(result[i]);         // Log the current result

    if(++i < length) {              // If there are more entries in the array
        setTimeout(iterator, 1000); // Log the next entry in 1 second.
    }
})();
```

Comment: Cerbrus, thanks, but that was the solution that I wasn't satisfied with :). The array in the sample code is very simple, but in the real app the matched set can grow to be very large, so I would rather not consume more memory if there is a solution that doesn't require outputting to a third array.

Comment: How _"very large"_ are we talking, @10basetom?

Comment: Cerbrus, up to thousands of items in `o` and hundreds of items in `a`. There could potentially be hundreds of matches, and each match can be a large object, so I'm trying to minimize memory consumption as much as possible.

Comment: @10basetom: I think you might be overestimating the amount of memory a array with (for example) 1k results takes. That said, The only way to find out what works best _for you_, is to try both T.J's answer, and mine.

Answer (score 1):

Take you code but change the output to a `push` into another (global) array. Then use a timer to print the array content one by one.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  o = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:10, e:11, f:12, g:7, h:8, i:9},
  t = [];

function matched(i, j) {
  return a[i]===o[j];
}

// function to output first element of array
function output(){
  if(t.length > 0){ // only generate output if array t isn't empty
    console.log(t.shift());
    setTimeout(output, 1000); // recall this function after 1s
  }
}

for (var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
  for (var j in o) {
    if (matched(i, j)) t.push(a[i]); // store all found items inside the new array
  }
}
output();
```

Answer (score 1):

An ES6 solution with a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator).

```js
function* getCommon(array, object) {
    var set = new Set(array), k;
    for (k in o) {
        if (set.has(o[k])) {
            yield o[k];
        }
    };
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    o = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 10, e: 11, f: 12, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9 },
    generator = getCommon(a, o),
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        var item = generator.next();
        if (item.done) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            console.log(item.value);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: If there's 10000 matches, there are 10000 timeouts pending at the same time. This method could be a memory hog for larger arrays.

Comment: The use of `Set` should include a compatibility disclaimer. You're also still calling `setInterval` _in a loop_, even though it will (should) only ever be called once.

Comment: @Cerbrus, now with a single call.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function which includes current `for`, `for..in` loop pattern, though iterating only single `a` element at `for` loop a function call while maintaining existing `for..in` loop; substitute returning a `Promise` which recursively calls function if incremented variable is less than `a.length`; else recursively return function with incremented variable, or if variable is `a.length`, return a value to `.then()` at completion of process.

This approach will make calls to `setTimeout()` sequential, without generating a pending call to `setTimeout` in future, next call to function is only made when current `setTimeout` completes, or no matches were returned for that iteration of loops.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
, o = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 10, e: 11, f: 12, g: 7, h: 8, i:9};

function matched(i, j) {
  return a[i] === o[j];
}

function matcher(index = 0) {
  var len = index < a.length;
  for (var i = index; i < index + 1; ++i) {
    for (var j in o) {
      if (matched(i, j)) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(a[i]);
          }, 1000)
        })
        .then(function(result) {
          console.log(`result:${result}`);
          if (len) {
            return matcher(++index)
          }
        });
      }
    }
  };
  return len ? matcher(++index) : "matcher complete";
}

matcher().then(function(complete) {
  console.log(complete);
});
```

Comment: You're potentially generating thousands of promises at the same time, each with a pending timeout. This'll be a memory hog.